# I was solving passcal's triangle problem and after implementing my logic I encounterd with this error

Tags: c++, arrays

Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9`

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> generate(int numRows) {
        vector<vector<int>> r(numRows);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numRows ; ++i){
            for(int j = 0 ; j <= i ; ++j){
                if(j == 0){
                    r[i][j] = 1;
                }
                else if(j == r[i].size()-1){
                    r[i][j] = 1;
                }
                else r[i][j] = r[i-1][j-1] + r[i-1][j];
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
};
```

Comment: I think you haven't reserved memory for your vectors.

Comment: `vector<vector<int>> r(numRows);` declares a vector containing `numRows` of empty `vector<int>`. So you're accessing them out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
vector<vector<int>> r(numRows);
```

You initialize `r` to be a vector of `numRows` vectors. The inner vectors are default constructed, hence are empty. If you want the inner vectors to be also of size `numRows` you have to either resize them or initialize them accordingly before you can access their elements:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> r( numRows, std::vector<int>(numRows) );
```

---

PS: This is potentially dangerous:

```
else if(j == r[i].size()-1)
```

`size()` returns an unsigned and when `r[i]` is empty `r[i].size() -1` wraps around to the maximum value of `size_t`. It is not an issue in your current code (once you have inner vectors of correct size), but better use this condition instead:

```
else if( j+1 == r[i].size())
```